# Replication of some Eureka behaviour with Consul

Tags: spring-cloud

As part of the move from Eureka to consul (Spring Cloud), we are looking at replicating certain behaviours.

One of them is that if a service disconnected to Eureka after a significant will reconnect when it can see Eureka again.

I see that a service will retry to consul and eventually stop.  Is there a way to replicate the same behaviour on a service to consul past the max retries/backoff?

Just trying to support expected behaviours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/197. That functionality you describe is built into the eureka thick client and something similar would need to be built for spring-cloud-consul.